# Is there a way to require explicit accessibility modifiers when compiling?

Tags: vb.net, resharper

Is it possible to make the VB.NET compiler either issue a warning or an error when compiling when it comes across unspecified accessibility modifiers on subs, functions, properties, and fields?

Failing that, is there anything in ReSharper that I could enable that would notify me of these issues?

Background: We have a lot of developers who are used to C# who leave off the modifiers, thinking the methods/properties will default to `Private` accessibility, when in reality VB.NET defaults to `Public`. I'd like to warn developers before the code goes to code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can setup a rule for this in [CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx), which supports code analysis in VB.Net.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I'll check it out. If I can accomplish it with the tools I already have, I'd prefer that route. But it is good to know that might be an option.

Comment: As an aside, VB.net defaults to private for fields

Comment: Good catch, peterG. I've updated my question to remove 'fields' from the list so as not to be misleading.